# Ruby Mysql2 via proxy (QuotaGuard)

Tags: mysql, ruby, heroku, proxy

I need to connect to a mysql database using [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).
Everything works well in local but on Heroku I need a static ip address so I have installed [QuotaGuard](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic) which provide me a proxy with username and password.

The proxy is working fine (tested with curl)

I'm not able to connect to mysql using it, I saw on a post that you can specify a mysql socket file while connecting but I have absolutely no idea what to put in it, can't find anywhere.

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => host, :database => database, :username => username, :password => password, :port => port, :socket => "my_path/to/mysql.sock")
```

I randomly tried this in `my_path/to/mysql.sock` but it doesn't affect anything, like it is ignored

```
route {
  proxy: xxxx:xxxxx@xxxxxx.quotaguard.com
  port: 9293
  proxyprotocol: socks_v5
  method: username
  command: connect
}
```

Thanks